# How to tweak a public key for Taproot

Tags: taproot, key-tweaking

From what I know, to tweak a public key, I can use:

```
Q = P + H(P|c)G
```

where

```
Q is the tweaked public key
P is the initial public key (P = xG where x is the private key)
H is the hash function
| is concatenation
c is the commitment to the script path spend
G is the generator point
```

This might seem like high school math but can I calculate the `H(P|c)G` part by using the result of `H(P|c)` as a private key and computing the public key from it? I think this might work because the `H()` returns a 32 byte array and the result could be casted as a private key then multiplied by generator point `G` to get the corresponding public key which is equal to `H(P|c)G`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. xG is the public key of x. So if you substitute H(P|c) for x then xG is now the public key of H(P|c). Is that what you are asking? You are effectively adding two public keys to get Q, the tweaked public key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly right.

Compute the tweak `H(P||c)`, compute the "public key" corresponding to that tweak, and then add (elliptic curve point addition) the internal public key with that tweak public key.